# Ansible - efficient use of set_fact with when clause

Tags: ansible

I have configured several `set_fact` tasks. However, to me it feels that this is not DRY.

For example, I configure 2 different tasks to set a fact based on a different when clause:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    installed: false
  when: "'abc' not in ansible_facts.packages"

- set_fact:
    installed: true
  when: "'abc' in ansible_facts.packages"
```

Another example I use:

```yaml
- name: set fact for bootstrapper
  set_fact:
    bootstrapper: true
  when: cluster.bootstrapper

- name: set fact for not bootstrapper
  set_fact:
    bootstrapper: false
  when: not cluster.bootstrapper
```

**Q:** Is there a more efficient method to set all these facts in e.g. a single task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of setting hard-coded boolean values based on boolean conditions, set the variables to the result of evaluating the condition.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    installed: "{{ 'abc' in ansible_facts.packages }}"
    bootstrapper: "{{ cluster.bootstrapper is truthy }}"
```

(You may need to adjust the second example depending on the expected contents of `cluster.bootstrapper` and the version of Ansible that you are using.)

Comment: What the heck, I didn't knew this was possible.

Comment: @KevinC Note that what is correct for `set_fact` is also correct for usual vars. Depending on your exact use case, you might be able to define them in your play's `vars` section (they'll be interpreted at any time you use them) rather than running a dedicated task for that (which "freezes" the value in the host's facts). Moreover, I personally would not bother reassigning `cluster.bootstrapper` and would use it as is. If you need to use it securely in a condition if that var can be undefined (example): `when: cluster.bootstrapper | default(false) | bool`

Comment: That's not the case. I need to use the variable a lot more in my role, and using that long expression for each task looks ugly. I simply want to 'beautify' my code, hehe. The actual example I am talking about: https://github.com/csuka/ansible_role_percona_xtradb_cluster/blob/main/tasks/assert.yml .Now I can make edits/improvements. It's all about these small things which in the end will result in good ol' looking code.